# My Ui hide Ads. I want how to find Ads's canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[my situation..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnlXx.png)

```
private void Win()
{
    OpenNextStage();
    CheckGameCount();
    Managers.Ui.SetSmallPopup(UiManager.SmallPopupUi.ClearPopup);
    _uiGamePopup.SetLineOnOff(false);
}

private void CheckGameCount()
{
    _gameCounter++;
    if (_gameCounter >= 1)
    {
        Managers.Ads.ShowInterstitial();
        _gameCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

this is my code.

my code make popup object after show Ads.
i want control this Ads's canvas, and change sort order.
but Ads object name is 768x1024(Clone). it's uneasy to be convinced of that always have that name.
how to find that object?? or is there any good way?

i use GameObject.Find() but this is not good way i think.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

Go to GoogleMobileAds Folder and set sort order of different ad canvases as in:

[image: Reference]